# div background color change back and forth with only one highlighted div at a time

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a horizontal nav bar that when each section is clicked the background color toggles back and forth. However I would like it so that only one section is 'active'. In other words only one section at a time can have a different background color.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="javascript:Tog('1')" onclick="changeColor(this)">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:Tog('2')" onclick="changeColor(this)">Legend</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:Tog('3')" onclick="changeColor(this)">Info</a></li>
</ul>"
```

Javascript

```
function changeColor(e) {
var c = e.className;
e.className = (c == 'color1') ? 'nav'  : 'color1'; 
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

By using pure javascript:

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#1" id="link1"  onclick="changeColor(this)">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2" id="link2" onclick="changeColor(this)">Legend</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3" id="link3" onclick="changeColor(this)">Info</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor(e) {
            var arr =e.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.color1');
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i].className = 'nav';
            }
            var c = e.className;    
            e.className = (c == 'color1') ? 'nav'  : 'color1'; 
            checkHashChange();
        }

        var currentPage = 0;
        function checkHashChange(){
            var newPage = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.length -1 , window.location.href.length);
            if(currentPage != newPage) {
                currentPage = newPage;
                changeColor(document.getElementById('link'+currentPage));
            }
            setTimeout('checkHashChange();', 100);
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .color1{
        background: #444;
        }

        .nav{
        background: #eee;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. This works in that only one section at a time can be highlighted. However if I click back on the same section it does not revert back to the original color. In other words, if I click a section twice, the second click does not change the color.

Comment: Is he not using pure javascript.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. Does that mean it can't be done using pure javascript?

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan. Hi I was wondering if you had a chance to look at my comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: You got to do polling to check the current hash of url to cater for back button on the same page

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't seem to change anything from before. I'll see if I can fiddle with it. Thank you.